# Angular - Chaining multiple observables together

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have three services that return observables. The first returns a list of recipes, the second gets all ingredients for a given recipe, and the last gets the quantity of a given ingredient type. I want to call all three consecutively passing the previous information along to the next call so that the returned responses can be mapped to the same initial list of recipes. Essentially each consecutive call would add to the previously returned info and the list of objects would grow in complexity with each successive call. I also need to apply a custom mapping to each return. I also need them to resolve at the same time so I can simply subscribe to the end result. I know I'll probably need to use switchMap or concatMap but I'm unsure of how to structure this.

Any help would be appreciated

Examples of my service calls and their mappings

Get recipes

```js
let allRecipes: Observable<RecipeModel[]> = this.recipeListService.GetRecipesFromAirtable(
      allTypes, allOccassions, allPrepStyles, allFamilies, muddlingReq, 
      allPrimaryComponents, allSecondaryComponents, recipeName
    ).pipe(map(response => {
      let allRecipes: RecipeModel[] = response.records.map(
        recipeObj => {
          //console.log(recipeObj.fields);

          let model: RecipeModel = {
            id: recipeObj.fields["Recipe ID"],
            name: recipeObj.fields["Name"],
            variant: '',
            version: 0,
            type: recipeObj.fields["Type"]
          }

          let variant: string = recipeObj.fields["Variant"];
          if(variant !== null && variant !== undefined) {
            model.variant = variant;
          }

          let version: number = recipeObj.fields["Version"];
          if(version !== null && version !== undefined && isNaN(version) !== true) {
            model.version = version;
          }

          return model;
        }
      )

      return allRecipes;
    }));
```

Get Ingredients

```js
let allIngredients: Observable<IngredientModel[]> = this.ingredientService.GetIngredientsFromAirtable(recipe.id)
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
      let allIngredientObjs: IngredientModel[] = response.records.map(
        ingredientObj => {
          let model: IngredientModel = {
            order: ingredientObj.fields["Order"],
            name: ingredientObj.fields["Ingredient Name"][0],
            qualifier: ingredientObj.fields["Qualifier"],
            optional: ingredientObj.fields["Optional"] ? ingredientObj.fields["Optional"] : false,
            amountReq: { },
            notes: ingredientObj.fields["Notes"]
          }

          let allFields: [string, string][] = [["Cups", "cup"], ["Ounces", "oz"], ["Millilitres", "mL"], ["Quantity", ""], ["Grams", "g"], 
            ["Dashes", ""], ["Barspoons", "barspoons"], ["Teaspoons", "tsp"], ["Misc", ""]];
          for(let i = 0; i < allFields.length; i++) {   
            let fieldName: string = allFields[i][0];
            let value: string = ingredientObj.fields[fieldName];

            if(value === null || value === undefined || value.length == 0) {
              continue;
            }

            model.amountReq[fieldName.toLowerCase()] = {units: allFields[i][1], amount: value};
          }

          // Add type info
          model.type = {
            superType: ingredientObj.fields["Ingredient Supertype"],
            type: ingredientObj.fields["Ingredient Type"],
            subType: ingredientObj.fields["Ingredient Subtype"]
          }

          return model;
        }
      )

      return allIngredientObjs;
    }));
```

Get Ingredient Quantity

```js
let ingredientQuantity: Observable<number> = this.inventoryService.GetIngredientQuantitiesFromAirtable(
      inventoryName, ingredientName)
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
        let quantity = 0;

        let allLiquorObjs = response.records.map(
          liquorObj => {
            let model = {
              brand: liquorObj.fields["Brand"][0],
              desc: liquorObj.fields["Description"][0],
              volume: liquorObj.fields["Current Volume (mL)"]
            }

            if("specialValue" in model.volume) {
              model.volume = -1;
            }

            if(model.volume > 0) {
              quantity += model.volume;
            }

            // return model;
          }
        )

        return quantity;
      }));
```

So far I have the following worked out thanks to Elias Dal Ben's help

```js
let allRecipes: Observable<RecipeModel[]> = this.getAllRecipesObservable(this.allDrinkTypes, 
      this.allDrinkOccassions, this.allPreparationStyles, this.allFamilies, this.muddlingRequired, 
      this.allPrimaryComponents, this.allSecondaryComponents, this.recipeNameToFind)
    .pipe(
      tap(allRecipes => { 
        console.debug('Recipes(' + allRecipes + ')'); 
      }),
      concatMap(data => {
        let allRecipes = data;
        allRecipes.map(
          recipe => {
            let allIngredients: Observable<IngredientModel[]> = this.getAllIngredientsObservable(recipe);

            allIngredients.pipe(
              tap(allIngredients => {
                console.debug('Ingredients(' + allIngredients + ')');
              }),
              concatMap(data => {
                let allIngredients = data;
                allIngredients.map(
                  ingredient => {
                    let quantity: Observable<number> = 
                    this.getIngredientQuantityObservable(this.inventoryAddr, ingredient.type.name);
                    
                    quantity.pipe(
                      tap(quantity => {
                        console.debug('Quantity(' + quantity + ')');
                      })
                    )

                    return quantity;
                  }
                )
              })
            )

            return allIngredients;
          }
        )

        return allRecipes;
      })
    )
```

However on the first line allRecipes gives me an error of

> "Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<RecipeModel[]>'"

and data in the second concatMap gives me an error of

> "Argument of type '(data: IngredientModel[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: IngredientModel[], index: number) => ObservableInput'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'."

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Its quite verbose but you could use `rx/operators` concatMap function

```
let result = allRecipes.pipe(
  concatMap(recipes => allIngredients.pipe(
     concatMap(ingredients => ingredientQuantity.pipe(
        map(quantity => [ ...ingredients, ...recipes, quantity ])
     ))
  ))
)
```

Then you could just subscribe to this result and have the `[ ...ingredients, ...recipes, quantity ]` structure or whatever your structure is

Comment: Problem is I need to incorporate the custom mapping or the objects I pass to each successive call won't be correct. For instance to get all ingredients for a given recipe I need to know the recipe ID. To get each quantity I need to know the ingredient type. How do I handle the mapping properly?

Once I get the allRecipes observable how do I get allIngredients for each recipe to pass to concatMap?